# Evaluation of Jacobian for Extended Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter, noise

For the non-additive noise case, 
\begin{equation} x_k = f(x_{k-1}, u_{k-1}, \xi_{k-1}) \\
y_k = h(x_k, \nu_k)
\end{equation}

the EKF takes into account the jacobian wrt to the noise terms $ L_{k-1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} |_{\hat{x}_{k-1|k-1}, u_{k-1}} $ and $ M_{k} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial \nu} |_{\hat{x}_{k|k-1}} $

I know that jacobian wrt to state: $ A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $ H = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ are evaluated at means of noises i.e. at $\xi = 0, \nu = 0$ resp.

But I'm not clear where to evaluate $L, M$ ? The above expression for $L_{k-1} , M_k$ tells only the $x, u$ but not the noise terms. Should  $\xi = 0, \nu = 0$ or some random sample?